# How was this formula derived?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I am solving this question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-sudoku/description/):

Determine if a Sudoku is valid.  The following one, for example, is valid:

[image]

One of the highly upvoted solutions uses a formula (taking advantage of integer division):

```
k = i / 3 * 3 + j / 3;
```

Now, this formula essentially maps a `3`x`3` matrix into a unique number such that this new 1 digit number can be used to refer to this particular grid (useful to represent it as an element of an array).  For example:

The following represents the 'mapping' of the `9`x`9` into a `3`x`3` grid (I have also marked those in the image above):

> 0 | 1 | 2 
>   3 | 4 | 5
>   6 | 7 | 8

Suppose, i=5 and j=6, (bottom-left index of the central grid on the right), then k (taking advantage of integer division):

```
k = 5 / 3 * 3 + 6 / 3 = 1 * 3 + 2 = 5
```

Where does this formula come from?

Comment: If anyone wants to see the solution, then it is [here](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8241/my-short-solution-by-c-o-n2).

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention in the question that the language being used performs integer division, so $(5/3)\times3+(6/3)$ can be evaluated as $1\times3+2$.

Comment: @postmortes, I agree.  I have updated the question accordingly.  Thank you  for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula is for a function which is a composition of two functions:

$$(i,j)\mapsto(i/3,j/3)$$

(where the symbol '$/$' denotes *integral* division) and:

$$(i,j)\mapsto 3i+j$$

which maps pairs $(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),\ldots,(2,2)$ to $0,1,2,\ldots,9$, respectively.

The *first* map converts the co-ordinates of a square in Sudoku to the co-ordinates of its containing $3\times 3$ square in the $3\times 3$ grid of the $3\times 3$ squares.

In your example, it maps $(5,6)\mapsto(1,2)$ because the little $1\times 1$ square at position $(5,6)$ is in the $3\times 3$ square which is in the $1$st row, $2$nd column among all $3\times 3$ squares (right middle-row $3\times 3$ square). Note all indexes are $0$-based.

The *second* map then maps that into the index $0-9$ of the $3\times 3$ square.

In your example $(1,2)\mapsto 5$, which is the index of the right middle-row square using the convention that you already have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Interesting.  Could you please elaborate a bit more, especially the paragraph below the equations?

Comment: @J.Doe I've tried. Please have a look.

Comment: The formula 'shrinks' the $3\times3$ grid into a $3\times3$ square.  Any cell in the first row ($9$ squares) of the _grid_ is mapped into the first cell of the  (new) $3\times3$ square.  Any cell in the fifth row of the grid is mapped into the middle cell of the square.  Try picking a row (fixing $i$) and looking at what happens to each square in it under the mapping

Comment: @user8734617, amazing.  I got your point.  Thank you! I wish I could upvote it more! :)